# Monitor PHP memory usage

Tags: php, memory

I'd like to examine the memory usage per-page on my website using Craft CMS. Is there a configuration option to enable memory logging or to display memory usage at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), then memory usage, along with tons of other debugging information (# of database queries, query profiles, execution timestamps, etc.) will be output to your browser's console.